# python2 vs python3 multiprocessing the difference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Python 2.7 -> 3.x Upgrade under consideration.

Multiprocessing is better performance?

Search results do not make a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change Python 2 -> Python 3 is (mostly) not about performance but about cleanness. Both language and libraries are made more consistent in Python 3.